# How to get matching lines from .csproj files and writing it to different output files using Powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have .csproj files in sub directory of c:\test\**\**\*.csproj

First i want to read the .csproj files, if pattren matches '< HintPath >' print all the lines with the matching pattern to output file with the name c:\output\new.(.csproj file name which it is reading)_QA_ABC

**Note: I need multiple output files with the names "new.(.csproj file name)_QA_ABC**"

I was trying this

```
     $configFiles = Get-ChildItem c:\test\**\**\*.csproj

        foreach ($file in $configFiles)
       {
         (Get-Content $file) | 
           Foreach-Object {
           if ( $_ -match '<HintPath>' ) | 
             % { Select -ExpandProperty line } | Out-File "c:\output\`new.$_`_QA`_ABC"
           } 
       }
```

Can someone help me

Thank You

Comment: please elaborate more on showing the result of your code and explaining the error / problem which you got

Comment: I'm new to powershell i don't think my script is right. It is giving PraseException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close.

```
Get-ChildItem c:\test\*\*\*.csproj | 
ForEach-Object {
    $_ | 
    Get-Content | 
    Where-Object { $_ -match '<HintPath>' } | 
    Out-File "c:\output\new.$($_.Name)_QA_ABC" 
}
```

---

`Get-ChildItem c:\test\*\*\*.csproj` gets all `.csproj` files exactly 2 folders deep from `c:\test`. (You could consider using `Get-ChildItem c:\test -filter *.csproj -recurse` instead which gets all `.csproj` files under `c:\test` recursively)

The output is then piped to the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet which essentially achieves the same thing as the `foreach` loop that you have. Piping inputs to cmdlets is more idomatic PowerShell. `$_` is the loop variable inside the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet. That is piped as input to the `Get-Content` cmdlet, then filtered to match `'<HintPath>'` and filtered lines are output to the file using the `Out-File` cmdlet.